# On click a mark should apperar on image with(pixel position) which will going to database for futher showing that mark

Tags: jquery, html

These codes are working good on localhost but not when uploaded to server.
On localhost on browser zoom in-out works good but same things not works online
This is Html Code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="large-6 columns">
<h3>(R)</h3>
<div class="divider"><span></span></div>
<div id="picx" style="background:url(img/large_eyeball.png);width:150px;height:150px;"></div>
      <div id="co"></div>
      <input type="hidden" name="inx" id="xaxis" value="">
      <input type="hidden" name="iny" id="yaxis" value="">
</div>
```

And little css

```
<style>
#picx
{
      position: relative;
  }

#picx img 
{
    position: absolute;
   }
</style>
```

And that is script

```
$('#picx').mousemove(function(e) {
    $('#co').text('x: '+ e.clientX + 'y: ' + e.clientY);    
    });
 $('#picx').click(function(e) {

     e.preventDefault();
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;


        var img = $('<img>');
        img.css('top', y);
        img.css('left', x);
        img.attr('src', 'img/cross.png');
        img.appendTo('#picx');
        $('#xaxis').attr('value', x);
        $('#yaxis').attr('value', y);
     });
```

Comment: in fiddle not coming mark. that might be outside of the picture like when i upload it to server http://jsfiddle.net/jw9cjjcy/

Comment: look at this http://jsfiddle.net/jw9cjjcy/

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/jw9cjjcy/4/)

> check this demo its working fine
>
> Change your Images as per your need.

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#picx').mousemove(function(e) {
        $('#co').text('x: '+ e.clientX + 'y: ' + e.clientY);    
    });
    $('#picx').on('click',function(e) {
        alert('adsf')
        //e.preventDefault();
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;


        var img = $('<img>');
        img.css('top', y);
        img.css('left', x);
        img.attr('src', 'cancel-128.png');
        img.appendTo('#picx');
        $('#xaxis').attr('value', x);
        $('#yaxis').attr('value', y);
    });
})
</script>
<style>
#picx {
    background:url(script.png) no-repeat;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;

}
</style>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <h3>(R)</h3>
        <div class="divider">
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div id="picx"></div>
        <div id="co"></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="inx" id="xaxis" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="iny" id="yaxis" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oops! not working to me. My screen resolution is 1440x900. So when i click on image mark start appearing top left goes successive to it. Not that place where i clicked.

Comment: how could I position the appended img to where I clicked?

Comment: please try adding positing : relative to the parent div.